# Mass Mail Plugin to Email Specified User Roles

Tags: plugins, email, plugin-recommendation

I'm not looking to spam anyone, but I am looking for a mass mail plugin so I can select the User Roles (whether core or custom) by check box or comma separated entries of the roles, then type my message and send.

The reason: I have a multi-author website with active contributors, authors and editors. I am looking for a simple way to email these groups.

I don't care if it is a free or premium plugin.

## UPDATE

I tried the solution provided below, [Emu2 - Email Users 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/emu2-email-users-2/), but after using it for a few days, I found there is a conflict with the WordPress media uploader, causing http errors on upload with the new WordPress uploader and timeouts using the classic WordPress uploader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress Plugin Directory - [Email Users](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/email-users/)

> A plugin for wordpress which allows you to send an email to the
>   registered blog users. Users can send personal emails to each other.
>   Power users can email groups of users and even notify group of users
>   of posts.

I also use the [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) plugin to hide Email Users from lower level user roles.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, exactly what you are looking for : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/emu2-email-users-2/

Comment: no prob :} i understand i did a huge search my self for this :}  glad i found it

Comment: I tried Emu2 - Email Users 2, but after using it for a few days, I found there is a conflict with the WordPress media uploader, causing http errors on upload with the new WordPress uploader and timeouts using the classic WordPress uploader.

Comment: i am using the latest wp version not breaking my upload, so i am not sure, ask help from the plugin author on its site, might fix it for ya :}